# Page keeps on reloading issue

Tags: experience-editor, horizon

We have an SXA site hosted in Sitecore 9.3, website browsing works fine.
When we installed Horizon on Sitecore 9.3 and started it to edit a page, but the page keeps on reloading, the horizon page editor doesn't work.

**Details:**
`Sitecore version 9.3 / SXA 9.3 / SOLR - 811`

**Logs:**

```
Start processing HTTP request "GET" https://sc.dev.local/sitecore/api/ssc/horizon/sites/-/getsites?sc_horizon=api&IncludeSystemSites=False
AuthenticationScheme: "OpenIdConnect" was successfully authenticated.
Sending HTTP request "GET" https://sc.dev.local/sitecore/api/ssc/horizon/sites/-/getsites?sc_horizon=api&IncludeSystemSites=False
Received HTTP response after 15.724ms - Unauthorized
End processing HTTP request after 16.1106ms - Unauthorized
**Error in GraphQL query (parsing/system): GraphQL.ExecutionError: {"Message":"Authorization has been denied for this request."}**
Connection id ""0HLU729VKDO3D"" completed keep alive response.
Request finished in 18.0592ms 200 application/json
```

Answer (score 1):

This issue occurs if the Sitecore Identity Server provider is installed, but it has been disabled. The Sitecore Identity Server provider is enabled by default in Sitecore 9.1+ installations, but it can be disabled for example using the `Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.IdentityServer.Disabler.config.example` configuration file, provided as example in the `\App_Config\Include\Examples` folder in the Content Management application.

The Sitecore Horizon on-premises installation guide asks to have Sitecore Identity installed before installing Sitecore Horizon, in the Prerequisites list at page 2. It could probably be improved saying this instead:

> - Ensure Sitecore Identity is installed **and enabled**.