# The page keeps loading endlessly

Tags: horizon

**Issue Details:**

While we are opening Horizon page from Sitecore launchpad / access URL separately, We are getting the following error

> The page did not load properly. Try refreshing the page. If the error
> reoccurs, contact your system administrator

The error occurs endlessly and getting **401 error** for the below URL

> https://****/sitecore/api/ssc/horizon/query/?sc_horizon=api

**We make sure the following:**

1. Identity instance URL is working fine and login succeeded to CM
   instance.
2. Horizon and CM URLs is correctly mentioned in
   `\{HorizonInstance}\Config\Host.xml`
3. Identity instance URL is correctly mentioned in
   `\HorizonInstance}\Config\OpenIdConnect.xml`
4. `Horizon.ClientHost` value refers to correct Horizon URL in
   `{CM Instance}\App_Config\Modules\Horizon\Sitecore.Horizon.Integration.Config`
5. `Sitecore.IdenityServer.Host.xml` refers correct CM and Horizon URLs
   in Identity server's path `\{Idenity Instance}\Config\production\`

This issue looks very similar to
`https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/27439/authorization-issue-between-horizon-and-content-management`.

However, I have tried the solution of negating the trailing slash as mentioned one of the answers, eventually no luck. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: What error do you see in the Sitecore log? This might be helpful https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/32256/unable-to-connect-to-site-and-see-site-content-n-horizon-10-1/32262#32262

Answer (score 0):

Eventually, the issue got resolved. It's due to the `"/"` trailing slash at end of the identity server URL. Sitecore support helped to find this tiny mistake. We corrected the below URL to make it work.

**Issue Prone URL:**

```
<sc.variable name="identityServerAuthority" value="https://{Idenity URL}`/`" />
```

**Correct URL:**

```
<sc.variable name="identityServerAuthority" value="https://{Idenity URL}" />
```